# Equivalent of sourcing ~/.bashrc when building Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have built a docker image (`lobis/geant4-root` which is on dockerhub) based on Ubuntu 20.04 where I have installed some software and placed the corresponding `source XXX` in the `~/.bashrc` file. When I run a container with this image in interactive mode with `docker run -it lobis/geant4-root` all the environment variables are correctly set as you would expect on a login shell. Example:

Running `docker run -it lobis/geant4-root`:

```
root@99261664efb1:/# geant4-config --version
10.7.1
```

However, when I try to build another image that uses this one as a base, I cannot find a way to load the variables from `~/.bashrc` to use them on the `RUN` commands. I have seen many questions related to this issue but couldn't get any solution to work.

I have tried changing the final line of the base Dockerfile to `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "-l"]` without success and tried to run my commands on the derived Dockerfile using a combination of `RUN bash -l -c 'command'` and `RUN source ~/.bashrc && bash command` without success. Also I tried setting up `ENV BASH_ENV "/root/.bashrc"`.

This Dockerfile should output `10.7.1` on the build log indicating that the correct version of the software is found, but no output is produced, and all subsequent commands that require this software fail.

```
FROM lobis/geant4-root:latest
# some of the things I tried
ENV BASH_ENV "/root/.bashrc"
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-l", "geant4-config --version"]
RUN geant4-config --version
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I am guessing this is a fairly common use case, as in my experience some software usually rely on loading though a source script, so please let me know the proper way to do this. Preferably I would like avoiding having to modify the base docker image.

Thanks.

Comment: Most Docker setups don't read shell dotfiles at all (and many don't even have GNU bash).  What commands are you trying to add to the `.bashrc` file?  Can you use the Dockerfile `ENV` instead, or install files into "system" locations (isolated in the container filesystem space) so you don't need special configuration?

Comment: I need to add two `source this.sh` commands into my `.bashrc`. They define many environment variables whose values would depend on the version of the docker image. Right now I am defining them manually on the derived Dockerfile, but this is not a good practice.