# Running a login shell in GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I want to use a login shell in my GitHub Action and after countless hours I cannot get it to work.

Here https://github.com/lobis/radiation-transport/actions/runs/1495875597 is an example of the failed workflow.

I am running the action from a container which itself has some software installed that initializes some key environment variables via bash script, which I have placed in `/root/.bashrc`.

The action (a cmake build) fails because the .bashrc is not being sourced (in particular it populates `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that is why it doesn't find the library and exits with error).

I have tried to source it in many ways from GitHub actions and the Dockerfile.

The most promising post is https://github.community/t/self-hosted-not-using-bashrc/18358/2 which defines

```
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -leo pipefail {0} # Removed " --noprofile --norc " options from default bash
```

but this does not work in my case.

I made a related post in the past ([Equivalent of sourcing ~/.bashrc when building Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560782/equivalent-of-sourcing-bashrc-when-building-dockerfile)) where I tried to source the .bashrc in my Dockerfile but I think its just not possible, so I think using a login shell in the GitHub action is the way to go.

After many attemps, I have managed to get it to work via sourcing the relevant files in each step of the action, but I hope there is a better way to do this. (example where it works https://github.com/lobis/radiation-transport/runs/4302779785?check_suite_focus=true)

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `~/.bashrc`, why not just set the env variable when you call cmake? eg `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/newlib cmake`? Or set the env variable in your actions config file.

Comment: Yes this would be a solution, the problem is that my docker image builds an arbitrary version of this software (defined via build argument) and the environment variables may be different between versions, so I want to keep it as general as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue as well. It was working fine until I update action runner version.

Then I realized I am using ubuntu as the base image.

so it should be

```yaml
shell: bash -ileo pipefail {0}
```